# Как привязать выполнение скрипта к флажку в Гугл Таблицах

Tags: google-apps-script

Есть скрипт

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('Hi!')
```

Что нужно сделать, чтобы при нажатии на флажок "истина" выполнялся скрипт, если "ложь" не выполнялся?

Answer (score 2):

Самое простое, что вы можете сделать - это проверить значение при срабатывании события `EDIT`

Для колонки `D:D` листа 'Sheet1' справедливо, если галочка установлена пользователем сейчас:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (
    e.range.getSheet().getName() === 'Sheet1' &&
    e.range.getColumn() === 4 &&
    e.range.getValue() === true
  )
    e.range
      .getSheet()
      .getParent()
      .toast('Hi');
}
```